# Host Docker application on Firebase Static Hosting

Tags: firebase, docker, firebase-hosting

How can I host an Docker container based app to Firebase static hosting ?

Is it even doable/allowed ?

Or should I host Docker based apps on services like Digital Ocean / Vultr / Linode / AWS instead ?

I'm using Firebase as my main database and since it comes with hosting in the same pricing model I would like to make good use of it and have everything on Google based servers rather than hosting elsewhere (such as Digital Ocean) and connecting to my database which would then be on Google.

Thank you

Answer (score 7):

Firebase Hosting is a static file host: it serves files without executing their content. While it was recently expanded to support [hosting of Express.js apps through Cloud Functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/functions), Firebase Hosting is not a generic docker host.