# How to configure firebase in order to interpret php files ?

Tags: firebase, firebase-hosting

I need to know how to configure my firebase account in order to host php files.I tried but whenever I click on the link to php file ,it just download the php files that I uploaded on my account rather than interpreting that.
Can someone suggest the way how to do so?

Comment: Firebase Hosting will execute your PHP code. It will serve them as raw files, as you've noticed. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46071760/host-docker-application-on-firebase-static-hosting/46078509#46078509, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28664997/upload-rails-app-to-firebase/28665286#28665286, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40955512/how-can-i-install-wordpress-in-the-firebase-hosting/40955984#40955984, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39522840/how-to-display-blade-php-files-using-firebase and probably more.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen ,there has to be some way that it can be done ,some plugins ,some library ,,something...

Comment: If you find a reasonable way, let me know. And post it as an answer to the other questions, because you're not the first to want this.